# Java applet Security Warning

Tags: java, security, applet

I have a problem with the Security Warning pop-up. If the user hits cancel or close the pop up  the browser remembers the decision and i can't show him the Security Warning again until the user restarts his browser. How can i achieve that?

So far i have tried this codes:

```
 <PARAM NAME="cache_archive" VALUE="xy.jar">

 <PARAM NAME="cache_version" VALUE="0.0.1.0">

 <param name="cache_option" value="no">
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why is the applet trapped in a browser?  Launch it free floating using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and the user can refuse it as many times as they like and accept it whenever they want.

Comment: Not trapped, java remembers your decision in the cache. If you empty the cache from java console it will asks you again. I cannot find any useful in Java Web Start...

Comment: You seem to have missed my point about JWS.  A free floating applet launched using JWS would not suffer the same problems as you describe.